# The process "...androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 14

Tags: android, qt, qml, qt-creator

I'm using Qt 5.12.1 on Windows 10 x64, and here is Android settings:

[image]

When building a QML program using the Arm7 kit, I get this code 14 error:

*The process "D:\Qt\Qt5.12.1\5.12.1\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 14.*

Here's also the SDK packages:

[image]

What's this problem related to, please?
Should I change any of the items NDK, JDK or SDK?
Isn't it an issue with the Qt Creator 4.8.1? From the time I updated some of the stuff above I get this error with this Qt Creator. Before that, it was working fine.

Do you have any idea to solve this issue, please?

Comment: Looking at the code for androiddeployqt at [woboq](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/tools/androiddeployqt/main.cpp.html#2992), it seems 14 means `CannotBuildAndroidProject`. Did you build with gradle or ant?

Comment: I use gradle I suppose. Should the gradle folder be inside the SDK folder to work properly?

Comment: are there any other warning before the "exited with code 14" ? Looking at the code, there are `fprintf`'s everywhere except for `mergeGradleProperties`, so depending on that you might get further?

Comment: I think there problem is almost exactly with gradle. [Here](https://codeshare.io/aJNO3R) is the whole error part of the compile Output window. By the way, the *gradle* I've put its address into *system variables* is **not** the one inside the SDK folder.

Comment: I think you should use the gradle from inside the SDK folder. And from the looks of the error-log provided you need to look at line 39 of build.gradle, you might need to put another revision, maybe Q instead of 29.0.0-preview? (no expert here)

Comment: There is no "gradle\bin" in the SDK folder. I also used another version of gradle, but those errors still exist! :(

Comment: Can you add the contents of build.gradle to the post?

Comment: I found the issue. Just will post the answer for other people facing such an issue. :)

Comment: Excellent, you should probably also mark it as accepted :-)

Comment: I will be able to do that tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with those packages in the SDK holding the "preview" description, in the above SDK list, say, "Tools Preview Channel" and "Q Preview". 
After deleting those packages and also the prior Android directory of the project all we need to do is rerunning qmake "*Bild => Run qmake*" and then re-building the project.
This time, the errors will vanish.